# twitter api 1.1 url count alternative

Tags: twitter, tweets

I've been using the old url api(v1) to get the count of a given url, lately I needed to get also the re-tweets and started searching about that.

this is the exact url I'm using right now:
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com

As I viewed with some reading the v1 api is deprecated but at least it's still working.

I found some questions on the dev page of twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12643

those are a little old questions and have no specific solving to the problem. I mean, the most near solution was using the search api(search/tweets) which  could be good but not a exactly replacement for the urls/count method.

> Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the
>   Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all
>   Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

also it has a limit for 100 results at maximum per 'page', even it throws the link to get the next set of objects, thats good but when the search reaches 1 million of results I'll need to get page over page to now how much tweets I got and having to do to much request to the api...

I sought some question over the dev page on twitter suggested using the stream api, I've tried using (statuses/filter) but that don't work very well given a URL as track param(which they said that is the keyword to track).

So, anyone who's been using the old urls/count has found a reliable alternative with the new apiv1.1, especiffically to get the tweets and re-tweets for a given url  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official suggestion by Twitter staff is that either the `search/tweets` endpoint (having just the last 7 days data) or the Streaming API be used (handling yourself the counters, making everything just too complicated for a d*mn counter).

As an extra warning, the old endpoint (`http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=YOUR_URL`) will stop working on November 20th, and according to [this blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform) from Twitter there are no plans to replace it with anything in the short term and they are even removing the count from their own buttons.

Comment: Some [extra info](https://twittercommunity.com/t/clarification-about-share-counts-for-the-new-tweet-button/52868/30)